# Passing shared_ptr per reference

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

When I do this:

```
#include <memory>

void DoSomething(const int& other)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>();

    DoSomething(*ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

When I pass the `shared_ptr` to the `DoSomething()` function, does it cause a copy of the object before passing the object because of the `*ptr`? Or is it fully passed by reference?

Let's say first I passed `*ptr` to a variable:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>();
auto aux = *ptr;//This causes a copy...

DoSomething(aux);
```

In the second case, it would cause a copy for sure. But in the first case, I am in doubt if a copy is made before passing the object by reference.

Comment: Your `DoSomething` function signature does not contain any mention of shared_ptr, so you are not "passing the shared_ptr to the DoSomething function". Instead, you are passing a reference to the thing owned by the shared_ptr. This reference has (by default) no link back to the shared_ptr so is only valid as long as this specific value in the shared_ptr is valid.

Comment: why not print the int before and after the call to dosomething and find out

Comment: It behaves as if `ptr` were an actual pointer, i.e. an `int*`.

Comment: pm100 make sense. I will do it

Comment: I tested in the first case yes it is passed by reference and in the second case by value. Thanks.

Comment: if you type `auto& aux = *ptr;` it doesn't cause copy. `*ptr` ([`shared_ptr::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*)) itself would never cause copy.